# How to notify parent when any child dispatches?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I `notify` a parent component when any deeply nested `children` component `dispatches`?

e.g.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that children can be of any depth, e.g.

```
<Component1>
    <Component2>
        <ComponentThatWillDispatch />
    </Component2>
</Component1>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dispatches"? The parent's `componentDidMount` method should be called after all children are rendered. Individual components can also implement `componentDidMount` to call a parent method. But shame on you if you are wanting to use this to change the state of something.

Comment: If you want to broadcast dispatches, then you'll need to pass some kind of function (eg didDispatch) down from the parent to each child, and then each child will call this.

Comment: @RyanWheale: By dispatches, I mean the child component calls a life-cycling method and performs an action on the redux store.
e.g. `this.store.dispatch({type:...})` 
I'm not talking about rendering.

Comment: @Mikkel: I don't want to map over the children, and clone the elements in order to pass some prop. This can be `n` number in depth.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to get notified from child to parent ,**

> 1. ComponentWillReceiveProps ,
> 2. Pass an action from parent to child ,

**ComponentWillReceiveProps**

It will return and previous Props and new Props , so that component will be notified

**Passing action as a parameter**

So that your actions will be triggered from your child component but it is dispatched from parent so your parent componwent will know the function has been triggered

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
      this.myAction= this.myAction.bind(this); 
    } 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Component1>
                <Component2 >
                    <ComponentThatWillDispatch myaction={this.myAction}/>
                </Component2>
            </Component1>
            </div>
        );
    }
    myAction(){
      alert("Called ")
    }
}
```

**You have to import your components**

Comment: Isn't `componentWillReceiveProps` for all props, not only its children props?